# Fetching value from URL, Commentics

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a little problem with programming.

I'm trying to make a website in which people could leave their humble opinions about each other.

I was looking into one page, http://numeris.info and they seem to use very simple but also very good which would suit my needs. basically, you type in after / number and it gives info about it from database, for ex :myawesomepage.co.uk/1234567890
I'm using Commentics review system if that helps.
it fetches all data with identifier

> `$cmtx_identifier = 'x';`

Is it possible somehow to fetch the digits from URL after slash and put them instead of x ?
and, if the digit doesnt exist in system, is it possible to 'create' a page?

Sorry if its to many questions, I'm just trying to learn programming, and many thanks

Comment: Use a rewrite rule on the server to change it to a URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Your `page.php`

```
<?php
$id = (int) $_GET["id"];
var_dump($id)
```

Comment: Well I got the part with ?id= , it loads a page. But how to make it to create a page if it doesnt exist?
for ex:
?id=1 exists, ok lets load it from mysql using id 1 
?id=500 doesnt exist, ok lets load the comment system and create a new id
'<?php
$cmtx_identifier = $id;
$cmtx_reference  = 'Page One';
$cmtx_folder     = '/nuomones/c/upload/';
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $cmtx_folder . 'frontend/index.php');
?>'
this is the script to load comment system.

Comment: You have to add a condition if the first of your page to check if it exists or not, if not redirect to 404 page